# Use Workflow to move Issue Tracking Item marked "Resolve" to a different Issue Tracking app?

Tags: workflow, issue-tracking

I'm fairly new to SharePoint Designer (2013), and I've created an Issue Tracking app page to track open items in my project group. The list is growing, and I want the page to drop all the Issues marked as "Resolved" from the "Issue Status" field into a new App in the same SharePoint domain.

I'm struggling to find a workflow that fits my needs, is there some way to copy/transfer an Issue once the Issue Status column is marked "Resolved"?

Thanks!!
Dan